# Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE using oracle.jd

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am using ojdbc7 driver in NetBeans but while connecting it shows the following error:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE using oracle.jd

Comment: Prity , your question is pretty vague, I would suggest that you add some more details before the stackoverflow police downvote you. Firstly you should probably put this in the java section, and secondly , can you show some source code of where you are trying to connect.

Comment: Also,  please post the entire error message, that will help us help you.

Comment: Do you have a listener listening on port 1521 on localhost (127.0.01)? Or on a LAN address, or a different port, or not running at all? Is the XE SID included in the listener config? Does using the service name instead `...@localhost:1521/XE` make any difference?